# How to give warning message in Visual Studio when passed an unappropriate parameter to a method?

Tags: visual-studio, attributes, compiler-warnings

I know that it is nonsense (or there is no chance) for variables that its value is unknowable until the runtime.

Let's assume that you have a method like this:

```
public void Foo (BarEnum barVal)
{
  //...
  if(barVal == BarEnum.UnappropriateForFooMethod)
     throw new BlaBlaException("Invalid barVal for Foo method ->" + barVal);

  //...
}
```

This method will already throw an exception for unappropriate parameter. But I intend to warn developer that before run code and get an exception. Main idea is that. It is not important that if she/he do not care about warnings or turned off the warning messages, her/him code will get an exception anyway.

I guess that it is possible with built-in attributes. Like `Obsolete`. But I could not find anything...

If there is no attribute for this purpose, I am open to suggestions for custom solutions.

Comment: If my answer is the accepted answer for the question then you should accept it by clicking the hollow check mark next to the answer, so that it becomes green. If you found a different solution then you should describe it here and accept it.

Comment: Yes, I know and would do it. No worry! Thank you for interest. I put your suggestions down but cannot get a change to look them. Just I am waiting to find enough time. Because they are great suggestions! And they needs much time than I have.

Answer (score 1):

From .NET Framework 4 and later there's something called [Code Contracts](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264808%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (on [GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/CodeContracts)). Never tried it, but looks like what you seek.

There's also [Roslyn](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn). Also haven't work with it, but probably does at least something that you want. Being a super-tool, it is probably a bit unwieldy and verbose for your needs.

One workaround to this problem, without using external tools, is to thoroughly review the code.